# Loading Images In sass with webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, sass

So I'm trying to load images from sass on an app I'm doing but I can't seem to find the right way currently I want to load

```
$navbar-brand-logo: url('../../../public/images/logo.png') !default;
```

I keep getting that the image can't be found, this is the sass part of my web pack config:

```
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.js$/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            query: {
                presets: ['react-app'],
                cacheDirectory: '.babel-cache'
            }
        }, {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            loader: [
                'css-hot-loader'
            ].concat(
                ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    fallback: 'style-loader',
                    use: ['css-loader', 'sass-loader']
                })
            )
        }, {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
        }, {
            exclude: [
                /\.html$/,
                /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                /\.json$/,
                /\.s?css$/,
                /\.(jpg|png)/
            ],
            loader: 'url-loader',
            options: {name: '[name].[ext]', limit: 30000}
        }, {
            test: /\.(jpg|png)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {name: '[name].[ext]'}
        }]
    },
```

Comment: What is the url that sass is resolving to after your app has compiled?

Comment: an image i want to use as background